# How do I change the default save location in Vim?

Tags: windows, vim, directory

Currently it's `C:\Windows\System32` which is pretty impractical. I know that you can change the current directory with `:cd [directory]`, but is there any way to change the default save location for new files without having to change directories all the time?

Comment: maybe set `TEMPDIR` or `TMPDIR`, or switch to Linux!

Comment: the last option is always right. @BasileStarynkevitch

Answer (score 5):

I am not at Windows so I cannot find the exact menu names and such, but if I recall correctly the easiest way to go about it is:

1. Find your gVim application
2. Right click it
3. Choose `Properties`,
4. Change the startup location in one of the tabs. The usual place to set it to would be your home directory.

Comment: Actually the latest version of the Vim installer (as of 7.4.077) will create the Vim shortcuts to point to the user directory as the startup directory instead of a non-writable location. So this was acknowledged as an issue with the installer and fixed.

Comment: I don't think he implied he was using gVim.

Answer (score 4):

You can change Vim's current working directory with the :cd command. 
See

```
 :help :cd
```

.

```
If you want Vim to always start in a particular directory, you can 
put the :cd command in your ~/_vimrc file.



If you want Vim to use 
the parent directory of the file you are editing as its current 
working directory, you can put this setting in your ~/_vimrc file:
```

.

```
 set autochdir
```

See

```
:help 'autochdir'
```